# How does the RemoveRange() method work in a List<>?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

As in title. I know it probably merges 2 sublists before and after deleted items, but how does that method behave when removing LAST elements? In other words: does it somehow make a copy of all elements located before remove index? I'm just curious about perfomance of using RemoveRange on a giant List (let's say 5000 elements) just to remove f.e. only last 2 of them.

If it makes a copy then, is there a way to change some internal variable that sets size of the List (and treat rest of allocated elements as garbage)?

I only managed to find an info, that it's an O(n) complexity algorithm, but I'm not sure if the "n" by that case is a List size, or a number of items to delete.

Will be glad for any hint.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/y33yd2b5.aspx "This method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count." "The items are removed and all the elements following them in the List<T> have their indexes reduced by count." http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/02/23/c.net-little-wondersndashthe-listlttgt-range-methods.aspx "be aware that this causes the remainder of the list to need to shift down to fill the gap, which can be non-trivial.  However, it will not require a reallocation of the list because the size is potentially shrinking, not growing."

Comment: Come on you think that count is number to be removed.  Removing 2 from a list of ten will take the same amount of time as removing 2 from a million.  If you click the count in the documentation it links the List Count.

Comment: @Blam That's not true, unless you're removing from the end of the list.  If you're removing from the start of the list then it's the difference between shifting 8 items up in memory by two items vs. shifting 1,999,998 items in memory up by two items.  Those two won't be equal.

Comment: BTW, a list with 5000 elements is not giant. It's only around 20 or 40 kB (for the list itself, not the data in it) under normal circumstances.

Comment: @Servy But a list of 10 can only only be a list of 10.  That count in  the documentation is the list count as it is bounded on 0(N).  But still good answer +1.

Comment: @Blam The whole point is that the time it takes to remove a range of items is proportional to the size of the list (in the worst case).  If the list has a fixed size then everything is O(1).

Comment: @Servy And that is what I said.  "If you click the count in the documentation it links the List Count".  I was referring to the documentation link from Sam.  Count is on that page twice but the link clarified which count.  "Come on" meant no - but with no ? I understand it was not clear.   Not sure what you mean every is O(1) - a lot of List methods are O(N) but it is no my intent to disagree with you.  +1 good answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What it will do is take each item after the end of the range of items to remove and move it up in the list by the number of items that were removed.  In terms of performance implications there will be one copy for each item after the end of the range of items moved.  This means that it will perform best when removing from the end (it'll be O(1)) and perform worst when removing from the start (O(n)).

As an example, consider the following list:

```
index - value

0 - A
1 - B
2 - C
3 - D
4 - E
5 - F
6 - G
```

If we call `RemoveRange(2, 2)`  Then we're removing two items starting at index 2, so we're removing C and D.

This means E needs to be copied to index 2, then F needs to be copied to index 3, and G needs to be copied to index 4.  There is one copy operation for each item after the last item removed.

Note that because of the fact that you can move the entire block of memory "up" by two this ends up being more efficient in practice that copying each item individually.  It's a lot easier for a computers memory to move an entire block of memory up by some fixed number of bytes than to move lots of little sections of memory to different arbitrary locations.  It will have the same asymptotic complexity though.

Answer (score 15):

`List<T>` is just a wrapper around an array, called `_items` in the code below. The array might have more slots in it than there are items in the list, so `_size` is used to keep track of how many are actually valid. When you do a `RemoveRange(index, count)`...

```
_size -= count;
if (index < _size)
    Array.Copy(_items, index + count, _items, index, _size - index);
Array.Clear(_items, _size, count);
```

...it copies the items from past the range into the now-empty space, and clears the old items.

If you are removing a range close to the beginning of a large list then the cost is proportional to the size of the list, because so much stuff has to be moved down.

If you are removing a large range close to the end of a large list then the copying is cheap but the clearing is expensive, so the cost will be proportional to the size of the range removed.

Comment: Could you, please, go a little deeper on why clearing is expensive in second case? As I understood we have to clear only affected elements of the array, amount of which is not as big as `_size` or `_items.Length` in case of big list. For example if you are removing little range in big list near the start or near the end.

Comment: Does this mean I should use a `LinkedList<T>` If I know the list will be large and I'll want to remove items later?

Comment: @Jodrell Probably not.  When using a linked list the loss of memory locality results in very poor performance, even for simple tasks such as iterating the linked list.  While the Big O values of many of it's operations are low, it's uncommon for linked lists to be a net win in most practical cases.

Comment: @Eric: Thank you for your answer, but could you explain the last situation you described? How I see it, is that after copying, all of the stuff to clear will be placed outside (after) array's new length index, so there wouldn't be need for clearing anything.

Comment: @Tarec if the list isn't cleared and it is holding on to reference types or structures with a field to a reference type, they can't be garbage collected.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: If you are removing a little range in a big list near the end then the cost is cheap. If you are removing a big range in a big list near the end then the copying is cheap but there are a lot of items to clear.

Comment: @Tarec: The Grand User is correct; suppose it is a long list of objects that hold onto a lot of memory, and you remove a big range of them. You'd expect them to be reclaimed on the next collection. The garbage collector just sees an array; it doesn't know that no one will ever access them again. Clearing the memory lets the list tell the GC that those references are no longer ever going to be used by the list.

Comment: Note that this is a copy of the source code of RemoveRange (minus various boilerplate), available [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) .  In my copy, the specific file is `RefSrc\Source\.Net\4.0\DEVDIV_TFS\Dev10\Releases\RTMRel\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Collections\Generic\List.cs\1305376\List.cs` .