# Why List<T>.RemoveRange(index, count) changes value before index?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable, genetic-algorithm

I am implementing a classic genetic algorithm. In the crossover phase I am finding some strange behaviour.

```
private static void Crossover(ref List<CrossoverPair> pairs)
{
    var random = new Random();
    //TODO debug this
    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < pair.First.Chromosomes.Count; i++)
        {
            var locus = random.Next(1, 12);
            var crossoverLength = pair.First.Chromosomes[i].Genes.Count - locus;
            var swapFirst = pair.First.Chromosomes[i].Genes.Skip(locus).Take(crossoverLength).ToList();
            var swapSecond = pair.Second.Chromosomes[i].Genes.Skip(locus).Take(crossoverLength).ToList();
            pair.First.Chromosomes[i].Genes.RemoveRange(locus - 1, crossoverLength);
            pair.First.Chromosomes[i].Genes.AddRange(swapSecond);
            pair.Second.Chromosomes[i].Genes.RemoveRange(locus - 1, crossoverLength);
            pair.Second.Chromosomes[i].Genes.AddRange(swapFirst);
        }
    }
}
```

Each chromosome contains 12 genes. It swaps homologous parts starting from a randomly defined locus.  For instance, if we have `locus = 8` and `crossoverLength = 4`, we first remove genes from `Genes[8]` to `Genes[11]` using `RemoveRange`, then we add genes from another chromosome using `AddRange`.

Sometimes something strange happens: when we use `RemoveRange`, `Genes[7]` (for this instance) changes its value from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0. It doesn't happen on each iteration, sometimes everything works fine. I've noticed it happens more often for `locus = 7..11`.

It doesn't hurt algorithm too much (just more mutations :D). But does anyone know why it inverts values?

[image: Strange behaviour proof]

**Update:**

Thanks a lot to BJ Myers for irrefragable answer.
Everyone else, who will read this post later, will may be interested in, why does it happen. It is explained good [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064983/how-does-the-removerange-method-work-in-a-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RemoveRange` is not changing the value before the specified index.  The reason it appears to be is because your indexes are off by one.

Take a look at this line:

```
pair.First.Chromosomes[i].Genes.RemoveRange(locus - 1, crossoverLength);
```

If we assume (as in your example) `locus = 8` and therefore `crossoverLength = 4`, the desired behavior would be to remove the elements with indexes `[8]` through `[11]`.  But since you have subtracted one from `locus`, you are passing in `7` as the first parameter to `RemoveRange` and therefore removing elements `[7]` through `[10]`.

The correct code should not include a `- 1` offset for either of the calls to `RemoveRange`:

```
pair.First.Chromosomes[i].Genes.RemoveRange(locus, crossoverLength);
```

The behavior that you perceived as element `[7]` changing was actually the result of elements `[7]` through `[10]` being removed, and the element formerly at `[11]` shifting down into position `[7]`.  If your "genes" are always binary, then there is a 50/50 chance that the value would "change" as a result of the `RemoveRange` call.